# How to use Calculate with single condition on pivot?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

In my pivot table I added a custom column like this:

```
=CALCULATE(MAX([Column1]),FILTER(table,expr))
```

I want to add a new condition and after a few tries, this is working as I expected

```
=IF([Column2]>5, CALCULATE(MAX([Column1]),FILTER(table,expr)) + 10,  
                 CALCULATE(MAX([Column1]),FILTER(table,expr))
   )
```

but this function is quite long (because expr pretty much the condition), I wonder if there is a LET function or some way that can shorten the above function

```
=CALCULATE(  IF (
                   [Column2]>5,MAX([Column1])+10, MAX([Column1])
                )
            ,FILTER(table,expr))
```

However this formula doesn't work,
Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps `CALCULATE ( MAX ( [Column1] ), FILTER ( table, expr ) ) + 10 * ( [Column2] > 5 )`

Comment: Hi @JosWoolley, Great! This is exactly what I expected. Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome!